# Getting list of files using expect command in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, expect

How to get list of files using expect command in a shell script

My script shell:

```
remotepass="12345"

echo
echo "list files ssh"
echo "=========="
listDoc=$(ssh user@111.111.111.111 ls /data/dcrm_int/ftp/out/rpt/dwh/20200820/*DWH_CRM_SYS_OPERLOG_20200820*)
echo $listDoc

echo
echo "list files"
echo "=========="
for document in $listDoc; do
    echo $document
done

cat > expect_1.dat << EOF
    spawn ssh user@111.111.111.111 ls /data/dcrm_int/ftp/out/rpt/dwh/20200820/*DWH_CRM_SYS_OPERLOG_20200820*
    expect "*?assword*"
    send "$remotepass\r"
    interact
EOF
listDoc=$(expect "expect_1.dat")

echo
echo "result"
echo "======"
echo $listDoc

echo
echo "list files"
echo "=========="
for document in $listDoc; do
    echo $document
done
```

[image: result]

The result that I hope to get is like the first red box

Is there any way to show only files and directories

Comment: WT...?  Unclear for me.  **1** do not post images of text.  Your results should be cut-paste text inside the question, not an image.  **2** your script in it's first section does an ssh and gets the proper result.  Why use expect then?  **3** If you want password-less login using SSH, setup keys, do not setup expect.  **4** I am unsure what the question is here...

Comment: In the first section, I get the proper result but I have to enter the password.
On that PC, I can't configure the password, I have to use expect command.
The expect command returns the information that I need but it is at the end and I don't know how to filter to get only the path of the files.

Comment: As you can see, red-boxes don't get you any friends ;-) ... Use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to format as `code/data/requiredOutput/ExactErrMsgs` . 2) maybe adding `2>/dev/null` at the end of your `ssh` expect command will hide the unwanted banner data. Else, as it is a standard message (which, admitedly could change), you could add `grep -Ev '^spawn|^Authorized|^Password'` to remove the unwanted messages before they get to your loop. Good first question (except for the screen shots). Keep posting and good luck.

Comment: Expect uses the Tcl language which can handle strings. If you are more familiar with shell language, take a look at my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect/).

Comment: you can also redirect the output to a file and parse it with shell script.

Answer (score 2):

By default `spawn` echoes all that is sent as well as what is received.
You can disable this by adding to the expect script start:

```
log_user 0
```

This will remove the unwanted starting text.

An unseen problem is that the output contains carriage-return characters <kbd>control-M</kbd> at the end of each line.  You can verify this by doing

```
echo "$listDoc"|cat -v
```

where each line will end `^M`. This is because the pty used by spawn will inherit the current stty settings which includes `onlcr` i.e. convert output newline to carriage-return newline. You can remove these characters in several ways, but you can also just avoid them by adding to the expect script start:

```
set stty_init -onlcr
```

Another problem is that the output begins with a blank line. You can avoid this by adding

```
expect "\n"
```

just before the `interact`.

Make sure to double-quote variables in the shell:

```
echo "$listDoc"
```

Comment: Also `spawn -noecho`

Comment: Excellent trick with stty_init, I haven't seen that before.

Answer (score 0):

Please accept [@meuh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64711645/7552)

A shell tip, using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), read the *lines* of the output into an array:

```sh
mapfile -t listDoc < <(expect "expect_1.dat")
```

then

```sh
echo
echo "list files"
echo "=========="
for document in "${listDoc[@]}"; do
    echo "$document"
done
```

Read [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667)

---

Listing out meuh's advice:

```
cat > expect_1.dat << EOF
    log_user 0
    set stty_init -onlcr
    spawn ssh user@111.111.111.111 ls /data/dcrm_int/ftp/out/rpt/dwh/20200820/*DWH_CRM_SYS_OPERLOG_20200820*
    expect "*?assword*"
    send "$remotepass\r"
    log_user 1
    expect eof
EOF
```

It's often a good idea to quote the heredoc, expecially if you'll be doing more code in expect and using expect variables. Then, you can pass shell variables to expect through the environment:

```
export remotepass
# note the quotes in the next line: the whole heredoc is a single quoted string
cat > expect_1.dat << 'EOF'
    log_user 0
    set stty_init -onlcr
    spawn ssh user@111.111.111.111 ls /data/dcrm_int/ftp/out/rpt/dwh/20200820/*DWH_CRM_SYS_OPERLOG_20200820*
    expect "*?assword*"
    send "$env(remotepass)\r"   # using the environment variable
    log_user 1
    expect eof
EOF
```